# Integrating w.r.t. the pushforward measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

Let $X,Y : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be independent r.v.'s and $f$ continuous. Then $A \subset \Omega$

$\int_{A} f(X,Y) dP = \int_{(X,Y)(A)} f(z) dP_{X,Y}(z) = \int_{(X,Y)(A)} f(x,y) dP_X(x) dP_Y(y) $ by independence.

Now, what I would have expected is that the result is

$\int_{X(A)} \int_{Y(A)} f(x,y) dP_X(x) dP_Y(y) = \int_{X(A) \times Y(A)} f(z) dP_{(X,Y)}(z)$ by independence, so it boils down to the question whether $(X,Y)(A)= X(A) \times Y(A)$ which is probably wrong. Thus, I was wondering whether it is possible to simplify the first expression further in order to get two integrals instead of just one or whether this is impossible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with $(X,Y)(A)$?

Comment: @drhab $(X(A),Y(A))$

Answer (score 0):

With an arbitrary measurable $A\subseteq\Omega$ you won't get far:
$$\int_{A}f\left(X\left(\omega\right),Y\left(\omega\right)\right)dP\left(\omega\right)=\int f\left(X\left(\omega\right),Y\left(\omega\right)\right)1_{A}\left(\omega\right)dP\left(\omega\right)$$
and there is no way to write this as: $$\int_{B}f\left(x,y\right)dP_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)$$
unless $A=\left\{ \left(X,Y\right)\in B\right\} $ for some Borelset
$B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

---

In general if $Z:\Omega\to\mathbb R^n$ then measure $P_Z$ induced by $Z$ "comes in" if functions of the form $h\circ Z$ are integrated:$$\int h\circ ZdP=\int hdP_Z$$